# haskell-persistent: how to use a foreign key as primary key in a second table

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent

## UPDATE - found the root cause for the error - but don't know how to solve it

I just found out that the root of this behaviour is not caused by using `sql=…` but rather that I use the primary key of the first table as a foreign **and** primary key.

```
Post
  topic String

  deriving Show Eq

PostContent
  Id PostId
  content String

  deriving Show Eq
```

So the question remains:

**Can I express in persistent somehow that a primary key is a foreign key?** - as from an SQL perspective this makes sense (at least I think so)?

## ORIGINAL

I am doing a port of the haxl example by simon marlow [Fun With HAXL pt1](https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2015-10-20-Fun-With-Haxl-1.html) to oracle/docker - for a proof of concept.

I am using the existing sql scripts to generate the db (as in the real world case that I have the db tables are not in my hand) - I have the following db layout

### table postinfo

```
| POSTID NUMBER | POSTDATE DATE | POSTTOPIC VARCHAR2(512 CHAR) |
```

### table postcontent

```
| POSTID NUMBER | CONTENT CLOB |
```

### table postviews

```
| POSTID NUMBER | VIEWS INT |
```

Of course I want to express the relation that `POSTID` is a foreign & unique key in `postcontent` and `postview` in the corresponding haskell persistent `QuasiQuoter`. Following the [yesod-book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), the [wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#change-tablecollection-key-definition-field-name-andor-type-persistent--21) and the [test cases](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/persistent-test/src/CompositeTest.hs#L53) linked from the wiki.

I created the following template haskell splice:

```
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False} , mkMigrate "compositeMigrate" , mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False}] [persistUpperCase|

Post sql=POSTINFO
  Id Int sql=POSTID
  date UTCTime sql=POSTDATE
  topic Text sql=POSTTOPIC

  deriving Show Eq

PostContent sql=POSTCONTENT
  Id PostId sql=POSTID
  content Text sql=CONTENT
  deriving Show Eq

PostViews sql=POSTVIEWS
  Id PostId sql=POSTID
  views Int sql=VIEWS
  deriving Show Eq
|]
```

which compiles with an error

```
error:
    • Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘PostId’
    • In the quasi-quotation:
        [persistUpperCase|

Post sql=POSTINFO
  Id Int sql=POSTID
  date UTCTime sql=POSTDATE
  topic Text sql=POSTTOPIC

  deriving Show Eq

PostContent
  Id PostId sql=POSTID
  content Text sql=CONTENT
  deriving Show Eq

PostViews
  Id PostId sql=POSTID
  views Int sql=VIEWS
  deriving Show Eq
|]
```

One thing to note the following test case quasi-quoter - works,

```
  Citizen
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Eq Show
  Address
    address String
    country String
    deriving Eq Show
  CitizenAddress
    citizen CitizenId
    address AddressId
    Primary citizen address
    deriving Eq Show
```

Here is a minimal example reproducing both the error and some working versions just run (and change the `#define` line accordingly

```
> stack runhaskell --package persistent-template minimal.hs
```

### `minimal.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE CPP                        #-}

module Minimal where

import Database.Persist.TH

#define FAILS
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "It works"


#ifdef WORKS
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False} , mkMigrate "compositeMigrate" , mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False}] [persistUpperCase|

Post sql=POSTINFO
  Id Int sql=POSTID
  topic String sql=POSTTOPIC

  deriving Show Eq
|]
#endif

#ifdef ALSOWORKS
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False} , mkMigrate "compositeMigrate" , mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False}] [persistUpperCase|

Post sql=POSTINFO
  Id Int sql=POSTID
  topic String sql=POSTTOPIC

  deriving Show Eq


PostContent sql=POSTCONTENT
  post PostId sql=POSTID
  content String sql=POSTCONTENT

  deriving Show Eq
|]
#endif

#ifdef FAILS
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False} , mkMigrate "compositeMigrate" , mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False}] [persistUpperCase|

Post sql=POSTINFO
  Id Int sql=POSTID
  topic String sql=POSTTOPIC

  deriving Show Eq

PostContent sql=POSTCONTENT
  Id PostId sql=POSTID
  content String sql=POSTCONTENT

  deriving Show Eq
|]
#endif

-- UPDATE

#ifdef FAILSTOO
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False} , mkMigrate "compositeMigrate" , mkDeleteCascade sqlSettings {mpsGeneric = False}] [persistUpperCase|

Post
  topic String

  deriving Show Eq

PostContent
  Id PostId
  content String

  deriving Show Eq
|]
#endif
```

Comment: I think you should post it as an separate answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: I think that I found the cause - but I don't know how to solve it - it is definitely misworded

Comment: Ah, okay. One obvious question: You do know that there is no persistent bindings for Oracle ?

Comment: Hmm - I already started working with [persistent-odbc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-odbc) - it took me a while but I managed to send queries from Haskell to an oracle db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I express in persistent somehow that a primary key is a foreign key?

Yes. A sample code example assuming Sqlite as the database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-7.14
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package yesod
     --package yesod-core
     --package blaze-html
     --package text
     --package persistent
     --package persistent-template
     --package persistent-sqlite
     --package shakespeare
     --package aeson
-}

{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Logger (runStderrLoggingT)
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH

share
  [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
  [persistLowerCase|
Post
    topic String
    deriving Show 
PostContent
    pid PostId
    Primary pid
    deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = mockMigration migrateAll
```

On executing, you get this:

```
CREATE TABLE "post"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"topic" VARCHAR NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE "post_content"("pid" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "post", PRIMARY KEY ("pid"))
```

You can see in the above example that the `pid` column in the table `post_content` is both the primary key and the foreign key.